# 'A' versus 'an' usage

Tags: grammar

In proper English usage it's widely recognized to use 'an' in front of any noun which begins with a vowel. Ex. An apple instead of 'a' apple. The converse is true in regard to nouns beginning with a consonant. Ex. A banana versus 'an' banana.

However, my question revolves around nouns whose first letter 'sounds' like a vowel; but isn't. Ex. 'an' hour sounds considerably better than 'a' hour.

Thus, is there an established rule of English utilization saying a person must/should use an article such as 'a' in front of nouns which begin with consonants sounding like vowels?

Comment: It's worth explaining that "vowel" and "consonant" are phonetic concepts. Languages have vowels and consonants regardless of whether their writing systems use glyphs representing individual sounds or whether they even have a written form. When we say *letters* are vowels or consonants, we mean only that they most usually represent sounds of those respective types.

Comment: Thank you Green Grasso Holm for your input...food for thought. :)